# IE не видит flash-баннера

Tags: internet-explorer

Где-то на каком то форуме взял вот такую штуку для ротации баннеров. Проблема в том, что IE баннер не отображает. Подскажите в чем тут может быть проблема? В остальных браузерах всё ОК.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var formBanners = new Array(
        "<object ...>...</object>", 
        "<object ...>...</object>"
    );
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * formBanners.length);

    $("#banner").html(formBanners[index]);
});
</script>
<p id="banner"></p>
```

Comment: тут скорее всего проблема с тем, что в object'е... если просто добавить в код работает? а то ie оч прихотлив к значениям разных параметров...

Comment: если просто <object> прописать статически то всё ок. Где нужна ротация - делаю так как описано - не отображает

Comment: Вроде [работает][1], проверял во всех браузерах...

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/CEHyR/